# Listing installed modules in Python

Tags: python

Here is a basic code I came up with to list modules installed.

```
import sys as s
mod=s.modules.keys()
for indx,each in enumerate(mod):
    print indx,each
```

But what I am looking for is, it should only print out the parent module name like for

```
 numpy.f2py.pprint'
 numpy.distutils.atexit'
 numpy.distutils.sys'
 numpy.f2py.sys'
```

It should count it once as Numpy and move to look for next module and repeat same way...

Comment: And? Have did you try? It is straight forward splitting the module name after the '.' and storing the first part in some some list and adding a check for each further module found. What is the problem?

Comment: yes i tried and will post soon,  it is not my homework though, i was tired of forgetting that i have a module installed and sometimes instead of trying to import i download from the net... also have to work in memorizing things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys as s
mod=s.modules.keys()
mods_seen = list()
for indx,each in enumerate(mod):
    parts = each.split('.')
    if not parts[0] in mods_seen:
        print indx,each
        mods_seen.append(parts[0])
```

Comment: modules found are different if searched through python interpreter or through IDLE or through VIDLE Interpreter..
I have been experimenting a lot!!! 
why so ?

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys
print set([each.split('.')[0] for each in sys.modules.keys()])
```

Comment: for some reason it doesnt list numpy module :/

Comment: sys.modules is not list of all installed modules, It's list of loaded modules, if you add `import numpy` to top of the code, it will show numpy too.

Comment: exactly but sys.modules.keys() lists all the in my example i mentioned

Comment: Are you sure? If you're running your code on python shell, open a new python shell and paste your code there to make sure.

Comment: help("modules") lists more modules then the code above, but it is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

The system command `pip freeze` does just about what you want, however I'm not entirely certain if it lists all modules or only those installed with pip.

Comment: The latter. Plus, not everyone even uses `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __listAllModules(self):
    """ This method returns all the modules installed in python
        including the built in ones.
    """
    allmodules = list(sys.builtin_module_names)
    allmodules += list(t[1] for t in pkgutil.iter_modules())
    allmodules = sorted(allmodules)
    return allmodules
```